# How to sort dataframe by using variablename

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to sort an DataFrame by a column which is specified by an object.

What I want to do is

```
data <- dplyr::arrange(data, desc(`column_name`))
```

by replacing `column_name` to object like `str_c("column_", "name")` because I want to sort by condition.

Those codes does not work.

```
data <- dplyr::arrange(data, desc(str_c("column_", "name")))
data <- dplyr::arrange(data, desc(colnames(data[str_c("column_", "name")])))
```

My code returns

> "Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : columnlength"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to convert to symbol and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(stringr)
dplyr::arrange(data, desc(!! rlang::sym(str_c("column_", "name"))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know the symbol. Your option works well! Thank you your help again!

Comment: @wizu It is the `sym` from `rlang` or in base r` it i `as.symbol`